# Simple Temperature Converter 2 in C

Tags: beginner, c, unit-conversion

I finally got around to redoing my [Temperature conversion program](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/138661/104611). I incorporated many elements of everyone's comments, and am uploading the finished program. Any new, or problems that I missed? Maybe a few very late here where I am working. Main focus of this redo was keeping my functions short and single purposed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inter_face();
void welcome();
void option_prompt();
void input_temp_prompt();
int get_option();
float get_input_temp();
void display_F_to_C(float);
void display_C_to_F(float);
void display_off();
void display_error();
float F_to_C(float);
float C_to_F(float);

enum { F_TO_C = 1, C_TO_F = 2, OFF = 3 } option_type;


int main()
{
    inter_face();
    getchar();
}

void inter_face()
{
    int option = -1;
    float input_temp = 0.0;
    welcome();
    while (option != OFF) {

        option_prompt();
        option = get_option();

        if (option == F_TO_C || option == C_TO_F) {
            input_temp_prompt();
            input_temp = get_input_temp();
        }
        switch (option) {
        case F_TO_C:
            display_F_to_C(F_to_C(input_temp));
            break;
        case C_TO_F:
            display_C_to_F(C_to_F(input_temp));
            break;
        case OFF:
            display_off();
            break;
        default:
            display_error();
        }
     }
 }

 void welcome()
{
    printf("Temperature conversion Calculator!!\nPlease select an option:");
    printf("\n1.) F to C\t2.) C to F\t3.) off\n\n");
}   

void option_prompt()
{
    printf("Option: ");
}

void input_temp_prompt()
{
     printf("Temp: ");
}

float get_input_temp()
{
    float input_temp = 0;
    scanf_s("%f", &input_temp);
    return input_temp;
}

int get_option()
{
    int option;
    scanf_s("%d", &option);
    return option;
} 

void display_F_to_C(float converted_temp)
{
     printf("Celsius: %f\n", converted_temp);
}

void display_C_to_F(float converted_temp)
{
    printf("Fahrenheit: %f\n", converted_temp);
}

void display_off() 
{
    printf("OFF\n");
}

void display_error()
{
    printf("Incorrect input, try again\n");
}

float F_to_C(float input_temp) 
{
      return (5.0 / 9.0) * (input_temp - 32);
}

float C_to_F(float input_temp)
{
    return (9.0 / 5.0) * (input_temp)+32;
}
```

Comment: A link to the first try would be great.

Comment: @maxik https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138661/simple-temperature-converter-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Firstly*, I don't quite understand why are you declaring so much functions that consist of a single line dedicated to printing a string. They are only used once and in one file, so there's no need to use a function or constant. I suggest you to get rid of them and replace calls to these functions with their bodies. Also, put `break;` inside `default` case ([Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/201777/break-on-default-case-in-switch) you can learn more about the reason why you should do this):

```
    switch (option) {
        case F_TO_C:
            printf("Celsius: %f\n", F_to_C(input_temp));
            break;
        case C_TO_F:
            printf("Fahrenheit: %f\n", C_to_F(input_temp));
            break;
        case OFF:
            printf("OFF\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Incorrect input, try again\n");
            break;
    }
```

*Secondly*, I recommend to use `puts()` instead of `printf()` when printing simple strings as it is obviously simpler and places a newline automatically (And you use it often throughout your code). Note that this doesn't involve cases when printing formatted strings.

```
    switch (option) {
        case F_TO_C:
            printf("Celsius: %f\n", F_to_C(input_temp));
            break;
        case C_TO_F:
            printf("Fahrenheit: %f\n", C_to_F(input_temp));
            break;
        case OFF:
            puts("OFF"); // No need for printf()!
            break;
        default:
            puts("Incorrect input, try again"); // No need for printf() as well!
            break;
    }
```

*Thirdly*, I'd suggest to move the body of `inter_face()` function to `main()` as it is not used anywhere else and basically creates a [run loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop), so I don't see any reasons why you should place it in a separate function. In addition to this, you probably want to define your functions before they're used, thus moving all functions above `main()`. It's not necessary as the compiler will find them anyway, yet I reckon the source code looks better that way (Just imagine reading a book from the end to the beginning).

```
float F_to_C(float input_temp) 
{
      return (5.0 / 9.0) * (input_temp - 32);
}

float C_to_F(float input_temp)
{
    return (9.0 / 5.0) * (input_temp)+32;
}

float get_input_temp()
{
    float input_temp = 0;
    scanf_s("%f", &input_temp);
    return input_temp;
}

int get_option()
{
    int option;
    scanf_s("%d", &option);
    return option;
} 

int main()
{
    int option = -1;
    float input_temp = 0.0;

    printf("Temperature conversion Calculator!!\nPlease select an option:");
    printf("\n1.) F to C\t2.) C to F\t3.) off\n\n");        

    while (option != OFF) {

        printf("Option: ");           
        option = get_option();

        if (option == F_TO_C || option == C_TO_F) {
            printf("Temp: ");   
            input_temp = get_input_temp();
        }

        switch (option) {
            case F_TO_C:
                printf("Celsius: %f\n", F_to_C(input_temp));
                break;
            case C_TO_F:
                printf("Fahrenheit: %f\n", C_to_F(input_temp));
                break;
            case OFF:
                puts("OFF"); // No need for printf()!
                break;
            default:
                puts("Incorrect input, try again"); // No need for printf() as well!
                break;
        }
    }

    getchar();
}
```

*Fourthly*, you should put function prototypes, enumerations and other objects that carry data (Of course, prototypes do not carry data, yet they belong in header files) into a separate header file (For instance, `main.h`). That way your source file looks a lot cleaner, and if someone wants to use these functions elsewhere, he can easily find this header file with needed prototypes within.

*Fifthly*, I'd consider either merging or getting rid of `get_option()` and `get_input_temp()` functions as they perform the same task, just with different data types. I suggest to create a single function called `get_input()` that returns a float (Since `float` can be compared to `int` without requiring you worry about loosing precision) instead if you don't want to put them inside `main()` as we did with other redundant functions before. You may then compare these variables normally as *usual arithmetic conversions* from `int` to `float` will occur when comparing `float` to `int` (You can learn more about such conversions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073079/implicit-type-conversion-in-c), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759014/can-i-compare-and-add-a-floating-point-number-to-an-integer-in-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161199/is-relational-comparison-between-int-and-float-directly-possible-in-c)).

```
#include "main.h" // Prototypes and enum are there!    

float F_to_C(float input_temp) 
{
      return (5.0 / 9.0) * (input_temp - 32);
}

float C_to_F(float input_temp)
{
    return (9.0 / 5.0) * (input_temp)+32;
}

float get_input(void)
{
    float input = 0;
    scanf_s("%f", &input);
    return input;
}

int main()
{
    int option = -1;
    float input_temp = 0.0;

    printf("Temperature conversion Calculator!!\nPlease select an option:");
    printf("\n1.) F to C\t2.) C to F\t3.) off\n\n");        

    while (option != OFF) {

        printf("Option: ");           
        option = get_input();

        if (option == F_TO_C || option == C_TO_F) {
            printf("Temp: ");   
            input_temp = get_input();
        }

        switch (option) {
            case F_TO_C:
                printf("Celsius: %f\n", F_to_C(input_temp));
                break;
            case C_TO_F:
                printf("Fahrenheit: %f\n", C_to_F(input_temp));
                break;
            case OFF:
                puts("OFF"); // No need for printf()!
                break;
            default:
                puts("Incorrect input, try again"); // No need for printf() as well!
                break;
        }
    }

    getchar();
}
```

Also, be sure to check **[chux](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/139935/52915)**'s answer. It contains even more useful tips and tricks to improve your code. Especially `scanf_s()` checks, `option = -1` change and math simplification.

Comment: Why recommend `puts()`, yet still use `printf("Option: ");`?  Simply use `fputs("Option: ", stdout);`.  IAC, best to use what is most clear to read.

Comment: I totally forgot about this one. Thanks for reminding! I think it's better to leave `printf()` in that case to be as it doesn't force you to provide a specific stream, which is always `stdout` in this program.

Comment: If you're going to move the function prototypes to a header file, then there is no point in declaring the functions before the main function. Those can all be moved below main

Comment: Yes, I understand. That's why I mentioned it's not necessary, and that it's just my opinion that functions used in `main()` should be above `main()`.

Comment: @Aleks.M. Thank you for your post, it is tremendously helpful! So the main loop, or run loop should be part of the main function in a program such as this? Is there any advantages to this? Thank you!

Comment: @chris260 It all depends, but I'd certainly put the main loop into`main()` in such a program. It is too small and clear to worry about such decisions. Of course, if your program grows, you may consider separating logic (In GTK you have `gtk_main()` function which creates a loop for your GUI app, keeps you away from tons of different checks, while you can focus on creating widgets). In terms of advantages, you get rid of redundancy as `inter_face()` wasn't meant to be managed or interrupted in `main()`, just giving your loop a name. [Here](http://goo.gl/2d0eup) you can read more about `main()`.

Answer (score 5):

1. When *declaring* a function with no parameters, use `(void)`.  This will detect improper usage of the function.  Without a function signature, the declaration does not indicate anything about the function arguments, just its return type.  With a function *definition*, using `int foo(void) {` and `int foo() {` are the same.
   [C99 Standard: 6.7.5.3 $10, $14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

   ```
   // void welcome();
   void welcome(void);

   void inter_face(void) {
     welcome("Hello");  // compiler error.
   ```
2. Using `F_TO_C` as a function and and an enumeration is less clear than using distinctive identifiers.
3. Inconsistence use of constants `F_TO_C, C_TO_F, OFF` with -1.  If `option` is to take on symbols, rather than integers, use symbols throughout.  I'd expect an `OPTION_INVALID`.

   ```
   // int option = -1;
   int option = OPTION_INVALID
   ```
4. Not checking the return value of `scanf()` family of functions should fail any review.  User input is evil - do not trust it.  Better yet, use `fgets()`, then parse the buffer.

   ```
   // scanf_s("%f", &input_temp);
   if (scanf_s("%f", &input_temp) != 1) Handle_InputError();
   ```
5. Simplify calculation.  Code uses `float` as variables but uses `double` math.  Code converts `float` to `double` to do the multiplication and then narrows back to `float`.

   ```
   F_to_C(float input_temp) {
     //        double constant
     // return (5.0 / 9.0) * (input_temp - 32);
     // Just use float math.
     return (5.0f / 9.0f) * (input_temp - 32);
   ```
6. Unclear why `float` variables are used as they are best for space and sometimes speed and neither of those issues apply here.  Recommend `double` throughout.
7. Consider splitting string literals for clarity

   ```
   printf("\n1.) F to C\t2.) C to F\t3.) off\n\n");
   // vs.   
   printf("\n" 
       "1.) F to C\t2.) C to F\t3.) off\n"
       "\n");
   ```
8. Minor.  Use an automatic formatting tool.  Such a tool would not make a trivial extra space here.  Avoid manual formating.

   ```
   // Extra leading space.
    void welcome()
   {
       printf("Temperature conversion Calculator!!\nPlease select an option:");
       printf("\n1.) F to C\t2.) C to F\t3.) off\n\n");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just my quick 2 cents:

- I'd move all the prototypes in an external file, something like `temperature.h`.
- You use `option_prompt` only to display the prompt and then read it, so you're probably better off removing `option_prompt()` and putting that `printf` inside of `get_option()`. The same goes for `input_temp_prompt()` and `get_input_temp()`.
- I cannot test it right now, but what if the user inputs a letter, or something like `5/2` at any of the prompts? My guess is that `scanf_s` is safe only regarding memory allocation, I doubt there's any check on the type of value that you scan. To be safer, you should probably read input through something like `gets` or `getc`, check that it's something acceptable and only after that, assign it to a variable that you can then use.

Answer (score -2):

Similar to ChatterOne, i would suggest to consolidate your functions:

```
int get_option()
{
    printf("Option: ");
    int option;
    scanf_s("%d", &option);
    return option;
} 

float get_input_temp()
{
    printf("Temp: ");
    float input_temp = 0;
    scanf_s("%f", &input_temp);
    return input_temp;
}
```

Also it is necessary to check whether the provided input is valid:

```
int get_option()
{
    printf("Option: ");
    int option;
    scanf_s("%d", &option);
    if (option == F_TO_C || option == C_TO_F || option OFF) {
        return option;
    } else {            
        printf("Incorrect input, try again\n");
        return get_option();
    }
}
```

Note, that i have added an recursive call to get_option in the error case. Similar changes should apply for get_input_temp().

Comment: 1) `|| option OFF` certainly should be `|| option == OFF` 2) This `get_option()` may be an infinite recursion should user enter a non-numeric.  3) Using `option` without qualifying the result of `scanf_s()` is not robust programming.   4) `printf("Option: ");` on  buffered output lacks certainty it will display before user input is requested.  Better to `fflush(stdout);` before seeking user input.  5) Inconsistent coding in initialize of `float input_temp = 0;`, yet not `int option;`

Comment: Yeah, the == is indeed missing. Regarding the infinite recursioni am unsure what is better, exit the program or call again. Or would you count to N until you stop? Regarding the other stuff I am new here and dont know whether it is appropriate to just copy the original code. I wouldnt have written it that way on my own but in my opinion it is better to work with the provided code rather than complete new one?!

Comment: " unsure what is better, exit the program or call again. " -> Neither.  Better to consume the offending non-numeric input then solicit input again or return with an indication to that effect.  Should error/end-of-file occur, return a value to indicate that.  "better to work with the provided code rather than complete new one?" --> When OP  code is weak/faulty, better to use improved code.